# can you use backbone listenTo with jquery objects?

Tags: jquery, events, backbone.js

Such as those returned by `$("#mystuff")` etc?

For example, can:

```
$('#div').on(event, callback)
```

be re-written as:

```
view.listenTo($('#div'), event, callback)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No it turns out you can't.

> You've got jQuery for that.

According to [tgriesser](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/1935)

> Sorry, `listenTo` only applies to objects that have the `Backbone.Events` mixed in, so it would work on a `Backbone.View`, `Backbone.Collection`, or `Backbone.Model`, but not on a jQuery object.

dang.

[Some folk](http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/#event_handlers_outside_views) also suggest creating a backbone view rather than using jquery events.